# Widgets the Symfony way

Tags: php, templates, symfony, view, widget

What is "the Symfony way" of creating reusable widgets?

By widget I mean an object with behavior defined in PHP and associated template that can be rendered on different pages (controller actions).

E.g. tag cloud widget:

```
// TagCloudWidget.php

class TagCloudWidget {

    /** @var PDO */
    private $connection;

    public function __construct(PDO $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $tags = $this->connection->query("SELECT * FROM tags ORDER BY name");
        $tags->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "Tag");
        include __DIR__ . "/TagCloudWidget.html.php";
    }

}

// TagCloudWidget.html.php

<div class="tag-cloud">
    <?php foreach ($tags as $tag) { ?>
        <span class="tag" style="font-size: <?php echo $tag->importance; ?>px;"><?php echo $tag->name; ?></span>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

What is the best way how to do it in Symfony? How to make the widget's dependecies to be managed by DI container?

Comment: twig extenstions:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Twig extension might be way to simplify instantiation of the widget in the template - `{% widget TagCloud %}`. However, it doesn't solve anything else (dependencies, best practices of structuring the app using widgets etc.).

Comment: Take a look at this https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataBlockBundle. The general idea is creating a service that returns an associated html, so you can reuse that service wherever you want (controllers, twig if you declare it as a twig service, etc). In my company, we have decided to create ourself a system of blocks, where all the blocks implement the same interface and have their own tag. But that one of Sonata it's a good one too.

Comment: @marjoramfx Documentation at http://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/index.html is very terse. Do you have links to other resources?

Comment: @JakubKulhan This is the official website: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/block/master/doc/reference/installation.html. I do not know any other resources ;)

Comment: It's true that's is not very good their doc, by the way... If you need an example or you have any doubts, I might can help you. Just tell me in case. I've to leave now, but I can answer you tomorrow in the morning, just in case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use in twig:

```
{{ render (controller("AcmeDemoBundle:Default:widget")) }}
```

An in the controller you implement an Action method. This controller doesn't need to have a route defined, but it has to render a view.

```
public function widgetAction()
{
    ...
    return array();
}
```

That renders a view in

```
Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Default/widget.html.twig
```

Of course this has a downside because I believe that when Symfony renders the view of the main controller he has to make another internal request to the widget's action.
In this way you can use this action as any other actions, you have access to any service, to database, like a component in Symfony 1.4.

Comment: Exploiting controllers to achieve this functionality doesn't seem right to me. For example in Nette, there are controls https://github.com/nette/examples/blob/master/Fifteen/app/components/FifteenControl.php#L114 + https://github.com/nette/examples/blob/master/Fifteen/app/components/FifteenControl.latte that can be easily added to controllers/presenters https://github.com/nette/examples/blob/master/Fifteen/app/presenters/DefaultPresenter.php#L18 and then rendered https://github.com/nette/examples/blob/master/Fifteen/app/templates/Default.default.latte#L16 There is nothing in Symfony like this?

Comment: As far as I know, in Symfony this is resembles most with what you say.